# Diferença entre ViewResult e ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Qual a diferença entre ViewResult e ActionResult? Normalmente eu chamo uma View usando uma ActionResult, mas já vi código com ViewResult. Então surgiu essa dúvida.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ViewResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult(v=vs.118).aspx) deriva [`ActionResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx). `ActionResult` é abstrata, e serve como curinga no retorno, que pode ser:

- [`ViewResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve especificamente uma *View*;
- [`PartialViewResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve especificamente uma *Partial View*;
- [`EmptyResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.emptyresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve uma resposta vazia;
- [`RedirectResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve uma instrução de redirecionamento para outro endereço, não necessariamente do seu sistema;
- [`RedirectToRouteResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.redirecttorouteresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve uma instrução de redirecionamento específica para outro endereço do seu sistema, baseada em rota;
- [`JsonResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve um JSON;
- [`JavaScriptResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.javascriptresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve um código JavaScript gerado em servidor para ser executado em cliente;
- [`ContentResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve um resultado customizado, como uma string, por exemplo;
- [`FileContentResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve um arquivo. Equivalente a [`FileResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx);
- [`FileStreamResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve um arquivo cuja leitura é baseada em um objeto do tipo [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) ou derivados.
- [`FilePathResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult(v=vs.118).aspx): Devolve um arquivo baseado em um caminho de diretório do sistema de arquivos do servidor que hospeda seu sistema.

Comment: Gostei das explicações Cigano. Eu estava olhando a documentação do ViewResult e percebi que também é uma classe abstrata a dúvida surgiu porque vi um método de controlador usando a ActionResult e outro método de controlador chamado uma View usando ViewResult no lugar da ActionResult. Se eu entendi direito nas suas explicações, tanto faz eu chamar uma View com ActionResult quanto ViewResult?

Comment: Exatamente, `ActionResult`, por ser mais genérico, suporta não apenas `return View()` como também qualquer outro retorno como os mencionados na resposta. `ViewResult` vai aceitar, portanto, apenas `return View()` ou algum método que retorne apenas `ViewResult`, o que pode vir a ser um limitador.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta!

Answer (score 4):

De uma resposta do [forum do ASP.NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1448398.aspx): `ActionResult` é uma classe abstrata, e tem variás classes derivadas, incluindo `ViewResult`. Se você vai retornar em seu método um ViewResult, você pode declará-lo tanto retornando ActionResult como ViewResult.

Essas são algumas classes derivadas de ActionResult:

- ViewResult

  - Retorna uma view para ser renderizada na resposta
- PartialViewResult

  - Retorna uma view parcial para ser renderizada na resposta
- EmptyResult

  - "Nada"; uma resposta vazia (resposta HTTP com conteúdo de tamanho 0, ou 204 No Content)
- RedirectResult

  - Retorna uma redireção (HTTP 3xx) para a URL especificada
- RedirectToRouteResult

  - Retorna uma redireção (HTTP 3xx) para a rota especificada
- JsonResult

  - Retorna um dado no formato JSON (application/json)

Comment: Quem votou negativo? A resposta está correta.

Comment: Carlos, o código que fez originar a minha dúvida é esse abaixo. Dentro do próprio método foram usados dois tipos de chamar uma View. A Primeira usando ActionResult e a segunda chamando a sua classe derivada que também é abstrata, a ViewResult: public ActionResult Alterar(Produto produto)
{
 return View(produto);
}

public ViewResult Novo()
{
        return View("Alterar", new Produto());
}

Comment: Pro ASP.NET, uma *action* precisa retornar um `ActionResult`, ou uma de suas classes derivadas - no seu caso, não vai fazer diferença. Uma vantagem de se declarar o método retornando o tipo concreto (por exemplo, `ViewResult`), é que isso previne que no futuro alguém mude o tipo de retorno por engano (e isso quem vai enforçar é o compilador, não o ASP.NET).

Comment: Obrigada Carlos pela ajuda!