# Retornar uma PartialView no ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Ao retornar uma *PartialView* a minha *action* pode tanto ter como retorno uma *ActionResult* como uma *PartialViewResult*.

```
public PartialViewResult Franquias()
{
    return PartialView("_Franquias");
}
```

Ou

```
public ActionResult Franquias()
{
    return PartialView("_Franquias");
}
```

A seguinte pergunta [Diferença entre ViewResult e ActionResult](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124685/5846) já fala sobre o assunto, no entanto minhas dúvidas são:

Qual seria a diferença entre as duas opções? (essa já foi respondida https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124688/5846)

Mas ainda fica a seguinte dúvida: No retorno de minha *Action*, quando a mesma faz um `return PartialView`, o que seria mais apropriado de utilizar, o *ActionResult* ou o *PartialViewResult*?

Comment: Não vejo como duplicada, pois a outra pergunta é sobre ViewResult e ActionResult e a minha é sobre PartialViewResult e ActionResult, apesar da resposta falar o que é cada um dos tipos, mas minha dúvida não é respondida lá.

Comment: Pablo, é duplicada porque a resposta é exatamente a mesma.

Comment: o que seria a diferença entre cada um sim, está respondido lá, mas qual seria mais apropriado utilizar não é respondido naquela pergunta

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas você gostaria de saber quais são os cenários apropriados para usar a `PartialView` ou quando usar?

Comment: @gato fiz uma edição na dúvida. acho que agora ficou mais clara

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas A outra dup responde a outra pergunta.

Comment: Agora sim concordo que está duplicada, quando pesquisei a respeito só pesquisei dentro da tag C#.